# Did `gem install xcpretty` and it returned an error

Tags: macos, shell, rubygems

I was trying to install a gem, but it shows an error:

```
╰─ gem install xcpretty
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/.gitignore
```

I am under MacOS(version 10.14.4), ruby version 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18].

What could be this root cause?
Is it because I changed to `zsh` months before?

Answer (score 2):

My friend @retso shared the correct answer to me.

It's because I did not set `GEM_HOME`, which default is the systen folder(`/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0`). So I need to set it to the user folder by the following commands in my `~/.zshrc`:

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem/

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

And reboot the command shell, then it works!

The `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` of `gem` will change from `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0` to `/Users/allenlinli/.gem`(which can be checked by `gem env`) then.